# How to test the axios response of the Backend API on vue js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, axios

I need help regarding how to test the **get**, **post**, **put**, **patch** backend API responses using **vue js**?

Currently I want to understand about **unit testing**. I have searched for it several times but I did not get an example or documentation that is easy to understand. If someone has already implemented it in their respective projects, can explain it a little. Maybe some of you all can provide references or examples for testing **axios** on **vue js** if you don't mind.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of Vue.js to unit testing HTTP endpoints. Vue.js has no built-in mechanisms for making HTTP requests. I suppose if you were building a unit testing application framework, you could use Vue.js for the UI but a guide to building a very complex application from scratch is not a suitable topic for a SO question.

Comment: okay thank you very much for the explanation this is very helpful. I guess I can do that to prevent endpoint errors before they are deployed. like endpoits that haven't been merged into production yet. :)